# If value in E:2 exist in sheet1!B:B then copy value to the left of B:B

Tags: excel

It should be a vlookup I have seen it before but I cant get it to work

In sheet2 in the E column I have a list of unique strings. I have a similar list in sheet1 E column. In the column left to this one I have numbers.

I want to copy these numbers to sheet2 to the left of the cell in my E column if there is a match.

Comment: In Sheet2!F2 ► `=iferror(vlookup(e2, sheet1!e:f, 2, false), "")` (more information at [Our 10 most popular functions](https://support.office.com/en-ca/article/Excel-functions-by-category-5f91f4e9-7b42-46d2-9bd1-63f26a86c0eb))

Comment: [this link](http://www.excel-university.com/how-to-return-a-value-left-of-vlookups-lookup-column) may help, as mentioned by pnuts.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return *column D values of Sheet1* into *column D of Sheet2*, based on a match between their right column (i.e column E) you just need to enter formula

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!D:D,MATCH(E2,Sheet1!E:E,0)),"")
```

in cell D2 in sheet2 and copy down to the last row. It's not case-sensitive.